# Selecting children elements and not descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select tbody's children and not their descendants?  For example, using the following  jQuery statement:

```
alert( $( '.someClass tbody tr' ).length );
```

will yield a length of 2 using the sample html below:

```
<div>
  <table class='someClass'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>cell 1-1</span>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr class='level-2'>
                  <td>
                    <span>cell 1-2</span>
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class='level-3'>
                          <td><span>cell 1-3</span></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>cell 2-1</span>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr class='level-2'>
                  <td>
                    <span>cell 2-2</span>
                      <table>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class='level-3'>
                            <td><span>cell 2-3</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: On a side note, your table markup needs to be updated.  You cannot nest tr tags inside of td tags.

Comment: Your HTML isn't legal. You need a `<table>` before the `<tr>`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
alert( $( '.someClass > tbody > tr' ).length );
```

That's actually a css2 selector, which jQuery nicely implements.

Comment: The statement above still selects the children's children yielding a count of 6.

Comment: It is not a CSS 3 selector. It is actually specified since CSS 2.

Comment: Mmm... it shouldn't, but try this `alert( $( '.someClass > tbody > tr' ).length );
`

Comment: @stavarotti: You need to use two child selectors (my answer contains an example). The reason is that there are in fact 6 `<tr>`'s nested inside of `<tbody>` tags. You need to make sure that you only select the ones at the root.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)  `>`, which will only select direct descendants:

```
$('.someClass > tbody > tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `Element > Child` selector, there is also the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
var element = $("#element");
var children = element.children("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just not use Jquery and have `element.children.length` or even `element.childElementCount`.