# jquery select all parents

Tags: jquery, parent

I want to select all parent divs and these parent divs have children divs inside, i don't want to select children divs.

Example (I want to select `$('.level0')` divs only without using class).

I mean something like :  `$('#parent-container div:first-child')`

But this selects only the first div. So i want to select all first divs of (level 0 ) without using any class.

```
<div id="parent-container">
    <div class="level0">
        <div class="level1"></div>
        <div class="level1"></div>
        <div class="level1"></div>
        <div class="level1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="level0">
        <div class="level1">
            <div class="level2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="level1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="level0">
        <div class="level1">
            <div class="level2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="level1">
            <div class="level2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="level1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you want to use the class?  This sort of thing is what they're for.

Comment: Eh, what about `$("#parent-container").children()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting children elements and not descendants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822671/selecting-children-elements-and-not-descendants). You could also just [have a look at the](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: try $('#parent-container > div') [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/KnWaG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all `level_0` divs are children of parent container, just select parent container's children.

```
$("#parent-container").children()
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? It works in my jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Q84sC/ given your provided html.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
$('#parent-container > div')
```